# Display data in a table when a person's ID is found Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following problem. I have connected an api to my database and it works fine with angular, when I want to show all the data in the database, it shows me the information in a table

Tabla generate with all data from database [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qYQY.jpg)

However, when I make the request for only one id I can show the result only in input element with this:

```
<input type="text" matInput **[(ngModel)]="elector.id" name="id"**>
```

Tabla generate with a single request to database and the respond can only be seen in input label
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wTgA.jpg)

I don't know how I can call it to show the result in the columns. Thanks in advance,
This is part of my html code and the input that works ok

```
<div class="mt-1">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<ng-container matColumnDef="rut">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rut </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rut}} </td>
</ng-container>
 
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr> 
<input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="elector.rut" name="rut">
```

And this is from my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Elector } from '../models/UI-Models/elector.mod';
import { ElectorService } from './elector.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-elector',
  templateUrl: './datos-elector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datos-elector.component.css']
})
export class DatosElectorComponent implements OnInit {
electorrut:string | null | undefined;
elector:Elector = {
    
etc..
  }
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['rut','nombre','circunscripcion_Electoral','comuna','provincia','region','pais','mesa','local_Votacion','ubicacion'];

dataSource : MatTableDataSource<Elector> = new MatTableDataSource<Elector>();

constructor(public readonly electorService:ElectorService,

public readonly route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit(): void {

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
(params) =>{
this.electorrut = params.get('rut');

if(this.electorrut){
  this.electorService.getElector(this.electorrut)
  .subscribe(
  (sucessResponse)=>{
  this.elector = sucessResponse;
```

Comment: I don't think there are enough informations. At least show the rest request you are doing and what you have attempted so far and the error you get

Comment: @Zerotwelve Sorry, I forgot the images. Now I updated with a little more detail.
I just want to show in the table what is obtained by my get when I pass the parameter rut. If I pass it to an input, I can see it, but not in the table.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Elector is not connected to your table at all. You use [dataSource]="dataSource" but you don't update dataSource anywhere in your code. Also elector should be an array to display it in table. Look into this offcial example https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http

Here is simple example with route parameter and one table row with api request.

**component.ts**

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'completed'];
dataSource = [];
id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private detailService: DetailService
) {
  detailService.getDetail(this.id).subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      this.dataSource = [response];
    },
  });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Title Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.title }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Completed Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="completed">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Completed</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.completed }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you,@taras but I just want one row, not all my db data. I did this in the beginning just to corroborate that my connection was working, that's why I show the first table.
The second table is empty, but you can see in the console that made the request /: , 
I have a the GET​/Electores​/{ElectorRut} wich return the specific value. I can saw that in the console, but not in a table. So, that is my question, why I can show  some value from the response in a input, but not in a row

Comment: It looks like you don't actually fill the table. It would be better if you can provide some working example on online code editors, so we can try to correct your code.

Comment: Thank you ! this is my code  and you can see the table with this url : [SHOW TABLE FOR SINGLE ELECTOR WITH RUT](http://localhost:4200/DatosElectorales/18836609-0)

AND THE REPOSITORY
[REPOSITORY](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/elaaadani/DatosElector/csb-ilf3c7/draft/confident-mountain?file=%2FREADME.md)

Comment: fyi the code is in this route ....../ src/app/datos-elector

Thank you again

Comment: I created simple example of what you try to achieve https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6uened?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdetail.component.ts Detail page has parameter in router, it gets data from api and displays response in table. Hope that can help.